# Multiple versions of jQuery in Django admin template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin

Without specifying anything, the Django 1.2.4 admin templates include jQuery 1.4.2. I just downloaded the jQuery UI framework, which came with 1.4.4. Thus, I would like to use the UI framework with 1.4.4. However, I'm not sure how to remove it from the Django admin templates. What am I supposed to do in this situation?

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        # this will cause both jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.4.4 to be included. Not sure if that's a problem or not.
        js = ("js/foo.js", "js/lib/jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "js/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js")

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override _media property from ModelAdmin

Here is _media form actual django code.

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def _media(self):
        from django.conf import settings

        js = ['js/core.js', 'js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js',
              'js/jquery.min.js', 'js/jquery.init.js']
        if self.actions is not None:
            js.extend(['js/actions.min.js'])
        if self.prepopulated_fields:
            js.append('js/urlify.js')
            js.append('js/prepopulate.min.js')
        if self.opts.get_ordered_objects():
            js.extend(['js/getElementsBySelector.js', 'js/dom-drag.js' , 'js/admin/ordering.js'])

        return forms.Media(js=['%s%s' % (settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX, url) for url in js]) 
    media = property(_media)
```

But maybe there is a better solution